# angularJS update model association at registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using the module ng-token-auth for my angular/rails app.

When I register my new users, first I register them, then I log them in, and finally, I update a few associated Active records

```
$auth.submitRegistration($scope.user)
  .then((resp) ->
    $scope.user.created = true
    # We auth user
    $auth.submitLogin({
      email: $scope.user.email,
      password: $scope.user.password
    }).then((resp) ->
      # We create the address and then redirect to dashboard
      $http.post(ENV.apiEndpoint + "/api/v1/address", $scope.address)
      .success((resp) ->
        notifications.add("account_created_success","success")
        # We then display the corresponding form
      ).error((resp) ->
        # Error management
      )
    ).catch (resp) ->
      #Error management
  ).catch (resp) ->
   #Error management
```

All is well, except that on safari 5.1 on OSX, I get a 401 when posting the information to `/api/v1/address`. If I login right after, I can with no problem.
Also it works on all other browsers (the recent ones that I've tested at least).

Anyone is having this bug with ng-token-auth?
how can I prevent this from happening ? 
or should I unregister the user if it fails ? can I even do this ?
thanks

Comment: what is the status code when your submitLogin fails?  I think you need to give an error response code when it fails and handle it in the error case.

Comment: Figure out why it's failing (look in the server logs). Once you do that, you might come up with better ideas than looping and POST'ing until it works or unregistering the user.

Comment: Thanks for this but the problem is that I don't get any error message. I assume that it's the login failing but I'm not even 100% sure. And of course can't reproduce the bug.